# Is Google App Engine secure enough for financial applications?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am wondering whether Google App Engine is secure enough for financial applications? This would involve storing sensitive information, access to users' funds, etc. Are there any applications like that already running on App Engine?

Comment: Ask google to provide the relevant compliance statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of laws and not professional server administration because not everything is only about security in here. If you are in the US then probably it may work (you need to ask Google to confirm) but other than that probably not.